# Datagridview.SelectedCells order

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm working on a C# application that contains a lot of DataGridViews which are empty. The user has to fill them with copy/pasted data from excel. What I do is the following:

```
int i = 0;
string s = Clipboard.GetText();

// Separate lines
string[] lines = Regex.Split(s, "\r\n");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Separate each cell
    string[] cells = line.Split('\t');
    foreach (string cell in cells)
    {
        // If we selected as many cells as copied
        if (dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == (lines.Length-1)*(cells.Length))
        {
            dataGridView.SelectedCells[i].Value = cell;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I copy something like this (on excel):

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

My datagridview will look like:

```
6   4   2
5   3   1
```

I don't really know what to do to fix this... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you can create a datatable with the cells array and bind the data to the datagrid?

Comment: @RayMoonDay I don't know if it's a good solution considering I've got like 50 dynamically generated grids, I'm not really into memory usage so I don't know if it's that huge or not. I'm going to try this out anyway, thank you.

Comment: Why you may need dynamically generated 50 empty grids? However, if you could just print the variable 's' which is a copy of the clipboard, you may get an idea if t is matching your output or the real excel data order

Comment: @RayMoonDay The clipboard string is like: 1 tab 2 tab 3 tab return 4 tab 5 tab... etc which is perfect (and matches the excel data). The problem is the way the DataGridView is selected, if I select the top left corner and shift clic the bottom right the data will be ordered in a completly unlogical way (like I said on my main post).

Comment: Hi, try to do use for loop using the selectedRow and selectedColumn index, something referred here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx. Sorry i was about to frame the code, but my machine is going through some heavy installation. once done, may be i can help u with the correct code :) Try ..

Comment: I still can't make it work. I've tried creating a list of the selected cells, order them, and copy them but when i don't get horrible exceptions it doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`dataGridView.SelectedCells[i].Value = cell;`

with

`dataGridView.SelectedCells[(dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count-1) - i].Value = cell;`

Comment: This is a really simple fix because if I select from bottom right to top left it wont work. Anyway the user will have to carefull, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert your clipboard data to a 2-dimensional array. Remember length of each dimension.
2. Iterate through the selected cells and find the top-left and bottom-right cells. From that you can determine it is of the right size.
3. Using a double loop, map your clipboard data from array position directly to cell coordinate (not using selected cells) using the topleft cell coordinate as an offset.

Alternatively, rather than a 2 dimensional array, you could create a List of a small class/struct containing the properties Row, Col and Value. Then just iterate through that rather than the double loop.

Comment: I thought of that and actually tried it (but the other way around, by sorting the selected cells in a list and looping), thank you too :)